# Enable alerts for MySQL long running queries

Tags: mysql

My application is loading very slow. After doing some research I got to know that MySQL is causing this slowness. I have around 15-20 users that access this server. After preliminary investigation (googling and stackoverflow), I found out that they were some queries running at the time and those were the culprit. It’s annoying to run query every now and then to look out for the queries running for a long time. Is there a workaround for this and also get email/SMS alerts for it. How can I enable email/SMS alerts to look over those queries

Comment: There is no alerting ready for this. Slow queries may be logged when you enable it and then you may analyze that log to fix the queries (usually by rewriting them or adding proper indexes). If you want alerts, then prepare small script (bash/php/python..) which will issue the `show processlist;` statement and analyze the output, then send email when any query takes more than X seconds (or when there are more than Y concurrent queries).

Comment: @jkavalik Can you suggest any link to bash scripts that can help me in setting up mail alerts

Comment: I do not have any ready-made one at hand. We use PHP one for something similar (check the number of connections and in case of blowing the limit save some info to file and email admins).

Comment: @jkavalik Do you use any PHP tools to set up the alert mails. If so, can you tell in brief.

Comment: IIRC no - just "raw" php and mysql functions and the [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function.

Comment: @jkavalik I searched for the PHP function but it is difficult to script as I’m new to PHP.  I could manage to find few tools like MEM, monyog, pt_query_digest. But not sure how does it work, will do hands-on them and post the outcome here.

Comment: You don't have to use php, you can use any language your application is written in to write such utility/script.

Comment: Updating my findings here. Reviewed quite a few open source libraries, tools and searched various blogs  to finally ended up with https://www.webyog.com/product/monyog. The features I wanted was alert for queries running for long than the prescribed time range is available in it. Not much effort needed to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

execute below commands on mysql from admin/root user-

```
slow_query_log = ON;
long_query_time = 2;
```

Now get slow query log file path from belowcommand-

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'slow_query_log_file';
```

Now go to your mysql db machine and check logged slow queries and optimize them.

Note: By this you can get slow queries even without restart mysql service but for better do these entries in your conf file so that you can get slow logs even after service restart.

Comment: Can you suggest a way to automate this process and by setting up mail alerts when the slow query log is updated each time